# Tring to save sub_sub_field in ACF [wordpress]

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I have a group field in ACF (with social media links). So i write in a input form the link of my social media.

I want to save those in my ACF fields. I can acces twitter for example with

```
$social_links = get_field('player_socials', 'user_'.$current_user_id);
echo($social_links['twitter']['url']);
```

But how can i save this ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as per: https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/update_field/

```
update_field($selector, $value, [$post_id]);
```

#### Grouping:

```
//Group your data into an array:
$values = array(

    'street'    =>  $street,
    'number'    =>  $number,
    'zipcode'   =>  $zipcode,
    'city'      =>  $city

);

//Update the field using this array as value:
update_field( 'selector', $values, $post_ID );
```

Comment: Yes i've seen this, but by adding "$social_links['twitter']['url']" ass selector, it doesn't work. I use ACF for others fields and it works, it's because it's a groupe...